# Configure ObjectMapper for a RestController

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-restcontroller

I have 2 controllers in my Spring boot application: RestControllerA returns JSON using snake_case, and RestController2 returns JSON using camelCase.

Is there a way to easily configure this? I'm currently doing something ugly like this:

```
@RestController
class RestControllerA(
    @Qualifier("objectMapperSnakeCase")
    private val objectMapperSnakeCase: ObjectMapper <-- I shouldn't have to inject this in.
) {
  @GetMapping("/test-endpoint-1")
  fun endpoint1(): ResponseEntity<String> { <-- I shouldn't have to return a string.
    val employee = Employee(...)
    val jsonString = objectMapperSnakeCase.writeValueAsString(employee)
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(jsonString)
  }
}

@RestController
class RestControllerB(
    @Qualifier("objectMapperCamelCase")
    private val objectMapperCamelCase: ObjectMapper <-- I shouldn't have to inject this in.
) {
  @GetMapping("/test-endpoint-2")
  fun endpoint2(): ResponseEntity<String> { <-- I shouldn't have to return a string.
    val employee = Employee(...)
    val jsonString = objectMapperCamelCase.writeValueAsString(employee)
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(jsonString)
  }
}
```

**What I would prefer:**

```
@RestController
class RestControllerA {
  @GetMapping("/test-endpoint-1")
  @ObjectMapperToUse("objectMapperSnakeCase") <-- Nice and easy.
  fun endpoint1(): Employee {
    return Employee(...)
  }
}

// Similar for RestControllerB with objectMapperCamelCase
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only way this can be achieved cleanly is [to use JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345460/jackson-multiple-serializers-on-the-same-entity-when-differents-rest-endpoint-a).